# Java - Find where two images are the same

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am working on a thresholding algorithm. I am attempting to use two different algorithms then anding the resulting images to find where they both placed a black pixel.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public static BufferedImage andImage(BufferedImage one, BufferedImage two)
{  
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(one.getWidth(), one.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    result.getGraphics().drawImage(one, 0, 0, null);
    WritableRaster rasterOne = result.getRaster();
    WritableRaster rasterTwo = two.getRaster();

    int[] pixelsOne = new int[one.getWidth()];
    int[] pixelsTwo = new int[two.getWidth()];

    for (int y = 0; y < two.getHeight(); y++) 
    {
        rasterOne.getPixels(0, y, one.getWidth(), 1, pixelsOne);
        rasterTwo.getPixels(0, y, two.getWidth(), 1, pixelsTwo);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixelsOne.length; i++) 
        {
            if (pixelsTwo[i] == 255 && pixelsOne[i] == 255)
            {
                pixelsOne[i] = 255;
            }
            else 
                pixelsOne[i] = 0;
        }
        rasterOne.setPixels(0, y, one.getWidth(), 1, pixelsOne);
    }

    return result;
}
```

What it comes up with is an OR of the two images. I feel like this is a really easy problem but I can't seem to find what the problem is.

EDIT:
All of the pixels are either 0 or 255.

Comment: What does the getPixels method do?

Comment: @MatthewC [Here's the javadoc for `getPixels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#getPixels(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[])).

Comment: I've looked over it and looked over it. It seems fine to me, could you upload  the 2 images you use and the resulting image as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the numbers for black and white swapped. It should be:

```
public static BufferedImage andImage(BufferedImage one, BufferedImage two)
{  
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(one.getWidth(), one.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    result.getGraphics().drawImage(one, 0, 0, null);
    WritableRaster rasterOne = result.getRaster();
    WritableRaster rasterTwo = two.getRaster();

    int[] pixelsOne = new int[one.getWidth()];
    int[] pixelsTwo = new int[two.getWidth()];

    for (int y = 0; y < two.getHeight(); y++) 
    {
        rasterOne.getPixels(0, y, one.getWidth(), 1, pixelsOne);
        rasterTwo.getPixels(0, y, two.getWidth(), 1, pixelsTwo);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixelsOne.length; i++) 
        {
            if (pixelsTwo[i] == 0 && pixelsOne[i] == 0)
                pixelsOne[i] = 0;
            else 
                pixelsOne[i] = 255;
        }
        rasterOne.setPixels(0, y, one.getWidth(), 1, pixelsOne);
    }

    return result;
}
```